# postgres, database with schema in ruby code

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I connected to postgres database from ruby with no problem, but when they added schema , I got confused and go error , here is the code I am trying to run :

```
require 'pg'

 @pg_conn = PGconn.connect("xxxxxxx.us-gov-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 5432, '', '', "BRCArchive", "yyyy", "zzzz")

count = @pg_conn.exec('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "brcmanager.Agency"') 
puts count
```

I got this error :

```
Called from brc_migration2.rb:7:in `<main>'
brc_migration2.rb:9:in `exec': ERROR:  relation "brcmanager.Agency" does not exist (PG::UndefinedTable)
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "brcmanager.Agency"
                         ^
    from brc_migration2.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
@pg_conn.exec("set search_path=brcmanager;")
```

and then

```
count = @pg_conn.exec('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Agency')
```

Answer (score -1):

The error tells you what's wrong. The table `brcmanager.Agency` does not exist in that database, perhaps you misspelled it?

You can see what tables exist in that database by running this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'information_schema'
```

Comment: I don't know why : ERROR:  relation "brcmanager.agency" does not exist , and from pgAdmin4 it works.

Comment: Is it spelled lowercase? Your query has the Agency in uppercase. Postgres only treats unquoted names case insensitively.